# Tweening alpha with GreenSock

Tags: actionscript-3, alpha, tween, flash-cs6, gsap

Trying to tween the alpha of a `graphics` object in AS3 using GreenSock, but the functions are not working. Trying to tween to from alpha 0 to 0.7 in 2 seconds. The `fromTo();` method doesn't work either. I don't want to, but would I have to instead, use an incremental for loop to do this?—As this wouldn't give me control over the time of the tween.

```
public function overlayBox():void {

    var overlaySquare:Sprite = new Sprite();

    overlaySquare.graphics.beginFill(0x00000);
    overlaySquare.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, displayRes, displayRes);
    overlaySquare.graphics.endFill();
    overlaySquare.x = xScreenPos;
    overlaySquare.y = yScreenPos;
    TweenMax.from(overlaySquare, 2, {autoAlpha:0});
    TweenMax.to(overlaySquare, 2, {autoAlpha:0.7});

    addChild(overlaySquare);
    trace("overlaySquare index: " + getChildIndex(overlaySquare));
}
```

EDIT: I've fixed the fade from alpha 0 to 0.7 by replacing the TweenMax functions from above to this:

```
overlaySquare.alpha = 0;
TweenMax.to(overlaySquare, 5, {alpha:0.7});
```

However, there's a problem with the alpha tween when it's run with the rest of the program. The tween "flashes" and instantly becomes 0.7 (it looks like it's "jumping" from 0 to 0.7) as soon as you can see it. The problem has been isolated to the function which is being called after `overlayBox();` An overview of the program: an image is loaded in using loader. Inside loader, there is a `myTimer.start();`. This is used to run the rest of the program once the image has been loaded. The `overlayBox();` is the first method that follows and runs fine. The next method, `textAnimation();`, is what breaks it, and I have no idea why:

```
public function textAnimation():void {

        //set text format
        textFormat.font = "Helvetica Neue Light";
        textFormat.size = 28;
        textFormat.bold = false;
        textFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;
        //textFormat.letterSpacing = 5;

        //set text size
        var size18bold:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        size18bold.size = 36;
        size18bold.bold = true;

        // pass text format
        textOne.defaultTextFormat = textFormat;
        textTwo.defaultTextFormat = textFormat;

        var xScreenPosStart:Number = xScreenPos + 440;
        var xScreenPosEnd:Number = xScreenPos - 300;

        textOne.text = "Blah blah blah";
        textOne.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        textOne.x = xScreenPosStart;
        textOne.y = yScreenPos + 240;
        TweenMax.to(textOne, 14, {x:xScreenPosEnd, ease:SlowMo.ease.config(1, 0), repeat:-1});

        textTwo.text = "Blah blah blah";
        textTwo.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        textTwo.x = xScreenPosStart;
        textTwo.y = yScreenPos + 140;
        TweenMax.to(textTwo, 12, {x:xScreenPosEnd, ease:SlowMo.ease.config(1, 0), repeat:-1, delay:4});

        //add to stage
        addChild(textOne);
        trace("textOne index: " + getChildIndex(textOne));
        addChild(textTwo);
        trace("textTwo index: " + getChildIndex(textTwo));

        textOne.setTextFormat(size18bold);

    }
```

Comment: Did you try using just alpha instead of autoalpha plugin

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using TweenMax.from, set the alpha manually.

```
overlaySquare.alpha = 0;
TweenMax.to( overlaySquare, 2, { alpha : .7 } );
```

Comment: I've tried changing it to `alpha` rather than using `autoAlpha` like above but all that does is set it to 0.7 as soon as the graphic draws (there's no tween).

Comment: When you add it to its parent, is the parent on the stage yet? The Tween does not wait for you to add it to the stage. It starts *immediately* when you call it. So if you add it to the stage afterward, it would look like it was being added at alpha == .7

Comment: The problem is being affected by the function that runs after the overlayBox(); It tweens fine on its own, as well as when it runs after the displayImage(); function as an overlay. I'll edit it into my post.

Answer (score 0):

Give an initial value for alpha And  use tweenMax.To only

Have you activated the auto alpha plugin? If not, then do it by

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite; 
import com.greensock.plugins.TweenPlugin; 
import com.greensock.plugins.AutoAlphaPlugin; 

//activation is permanent in the SWF, so this line only needs to be run once.
TweenPlugin.activate([AutoAlphaPlugin]);
```

If you don't need auto alpha then just use alpha Property

I tried this:

```
private function _Show() : void {
    var overlaySquare:Sprite = new Sprite();
    overlaySquare.graphics.beginFill(0x00000);
    overlaySquare.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    overlaySquare.graphics.endFill();
    overlaySquare.x = 100;
    overlaySquare.y = 100;
    TweenMax.to(overlaySquare, 2, {alpha:0.7});

    addChild(overlaySquare);
    trace("overlaySquare index: " + getChildIndex(overlaySquare));
}
```

This works.

Comment: If you mean `overlaySquare.graphics.beginFill(0x00000, 0);` and `TweenMax.to(overlaySquare, 2, {autoAlpha:0.7});`, I have tried this before. The alpha channel stays at 0 forever and doesn't change.

Comment: Yes I've imported and activated the plugin but it doesn't tween. I've tried with just alpha but that doesn't work either. Also in this case, what would be the different between `alpha` and `autoAlpha`?

Comment: Read here: http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/plugins/AutoAlphaPlugin.html about AutoAlpha

Comment: I retried your code with alpha value as mentioned in my answer and it works perfectly. When you say the method doesn't work, do you mean that you don't see the added sprite or you see the sprite but you don't see the tweening

Comment: I just tried it again and have found a few problems. When run on its own, this is what happens: it tweens from and alpha of 1 to 0.7 instead of 0 to 0.7. When run as an overlay on top of a display image: it draws at an alpha of 1 and instantly "flashes" and changes to 0.7 without tweening.

Comment: Are you able to isolate the problem to just one function. Basically, create a blank .FLA file, attach the Document class and add the code for _Show() in the Document Class. Call _Show from constructor.

Comment: When isolated to just the _Show() function, using the exact code you have above: it tweens from alpha of 1 to 0.7, not alpha of 0 to 0.7. It needs `overlaySquare.alpha = 0;` to do this.

Comment: Right, it's not the loader which is causing the problem. It tweens when it's just running the displayImage() and overlaySquare() methods. Currently trying to debug it. It's the function after the overlaySquare() which is somehow causing this "jumping" problem. Should I edit my post to show the problem?